# How to apply JSON responseText to Google Maps in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

So in my Rails app I am building out a region show page with multiple locations. Users are able to insert new locations and map markers need to be dynamically placed based on the latitude and longitude that they enter. In my Region show page I have the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="banner" id="region-banner" data-region-name="<%=@region.name.downcase%>">
 <script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',app.regions);</script>
```

Then in my region.js file I have the following:

```
 import { tns } from 'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.module';
 import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';

 app.regions = () => {
   function init() {
    startGoogleMap();
   }

  let startGoogleMap = () => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('region-banner'), {
      zoom: 3,
      minZoom: 3,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
      styles: mapStyle
    });
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('region-banner');
    const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name');

    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    let promise = $.getJSON('/locations.json');

    promise.done(function(data) {
      return $.each(data, function() {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
          position: { 
              lat: parseFloat(data.lat), 
              lng: parseFloat(data.lng) },
          map: map,
          icon: "/marker.png"
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(promise);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };

  return init();
};
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
  def show
   @locations = Location.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @locations }
     format.html
   end
 end
```

So no real errors are applying however...nothing appears. The console shows the responseText:“[{“id”: 5, “name”: “Chicago”, “abbreviation”: “CHI”, “lat”: “44.222”, “lng”: “-22.111”}, {“id”: 6, “name”: “Frankfort”, “abbreviation”: “FKT”, “lat”: “41.3232”, “lng”: “-19.5221”} ]”. Which really on this page I should only need/use the first.

Shouldn't it also be applying the markers at this stage since I put in the position?

Answer (score -1):

this is the code responsible for setting your `Markers`.

I would focus on understanding why `promise.done()` does not run create the `new google.maps.Marker()` for each row in your `(data)` from your response.

Maybe the problem is connected to the `/marker.png`

```
promise.done(function(data) {
  return $.each(data, function() {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { 
          lat: parseFloat(data.lat), 
          lng: parseFloat(data.lng) },
      map: map,
      icon: "/marker.png"
    });
  });
});
```